# How to install a specific version of chromium for puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, puppeteer, apt

I use puppeteer for my project. I always installed both puppeteer library and the browser itself with the `npm i puppeteer` command. Now I want to install the browser separately.

The puppeteer version I use is 13.5.2. In the [documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/v13.5.2#q-why-doesnt-puppeteer-vxxx-work-with-chromium-vyyy) said, that it's guaranted to work only with specific browser version. The compatibility list can be found here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/versions.js

So, chromium 100.0.4889.0 matches my puppeteer 13.5.2. I try to install this version in Docker. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-slim

ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true

RUN apt-get update
# for https
RUN apt-get install -yyq ca-certificates
# install libraries
RUN apt-get install -yyq libappindicator1 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
# tools
RUN apt-get install -yyq gconf-service lsb-release wget xdg-utils
# and fonts
RUN apt-get install -yyq fonts-liberation

RUN apt-get install -yyq chromium=100.0.4889.0
```

There are more commands, where I install npm dependencies, but it doesn't matter, since I have an error on the last command:

```
 > [ 7/16] RUN apt-get install -yyq chromium=100.0.4889.0:
#10 0.212 Reading package lists...
#10 0.600 Building dependency tree...
#10 0.662 Reading state information...
#10 0.673 E: Version '100.0.4889.0' for 'chromium' was not found
```

Looks like only versions 73.X and 75.X could be installed:

```
root@077e9dcf4544:/# apt-cache policy chromium
chromium:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 73.0.3683.75-1~deb9u1
  Version table:
     73.0.3683.75-1~deb9u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main arm64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main arm64 Packages
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Chromium releases that Puppeteer downloads are not necessarily published to the package managers of operating systems. So it's likely that the exact same version is not available via the package manager. The same major versions usually have very few differences so if you download M100 via the package manager, it might work. To download the exact version you'd need to use the Puppeteer package (i.e., `npm i puppeteer@version` in your Dockerfile) or replicate the logic that Puppeteer uses to download the binary (although, that is not recommended).